# What is the difference in fieldLengh and avgFieldLength in Solr 6.6 vs Solr 7.1

Tags: solr

We are upgrading from *Solr 6.6* to *Solr 7.1*, we see lot of differences in raking and scores of *Solr 6.6* and *Solr7.1* results.

The major differences we observed are in `fieldLengh` and `avgFieldLength` parameters which are calculated per field, per document, per search term.

```
Calculation of tfNorm in Solr 7.1.0 -
tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:
**fieldLength 53272.000000000** 4087877% 4087877%
**avgFieldLength 7284.331000000** 558970% 558970%
termFreq=10.0 10.000000000 767% 767%
parameter k1 1.200000000 92% 92%
parameter b 0.750000000 58% 58%

Calculation of tfNorm for same in Solr 6.6.0 - 
tfNorm, computed as (freq * (k1 + 1)) / (freq + k1 * (1 - b + b * fieldLength / avgFieldLength)) from:
**fieldLength 65536.000000000** 5480182% 5480182%
**avgFieldLength 7284.830600000** 609164% 609164%
termFreq=10.0 10.000000000 836% 836%
parameter k1 1.200000000 100% 100%
parameter b 0.750000000 63% 63%
```

Can someone please elaborate on what differences are brought in *Solr7.1* for the `fieldLength` and `averageFieldLength` calculation?

Comment: If the fieldLength differs for some documents, wouldn't avgFieldLength differ by default? IIRC fieldlength is an 8 bit floating point number, so it isn't exactly precise - a small change in the actual length (i.e. whitespace, encoding, etc.) can result in a large change in the fieldLength value if it's just on the limit.

Comment: @MatsLindh - yes averagefieldlength is also differing, so for the same document, same field and for same search term the scores are different in Solr 6.6 and Solr 7.1, for example Solr 7.1 score - fieldLength
53272.000000000
10753569%
10753569%
avgFieldLength
7284.331000000
1470426%
1470426%

Comment: My point is that if fieldlength differs, average field length will differ as well - since it's the average of all the field length values. I'd start by finding a small field and seeing if the length differs there as well, then look at how the indexed content differs (.. or it can be a change to how the value is being encoded between the versions).

Comment: Agreed, I also observed difference in FieldLengthFeature implementation of Solr 6.6 vs Solr7, not sure if its bug fix or improvement and related to this issue at all- Solr 6.6 implementation -   static {
    NORM_TABLE[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
      float norm = SmallFloat.byte315ToFloat((byte) i);
      NORM_TABLE[i] = 1.0f / (norm * norm);
    }
  }  and Solr 7.1 -   static {
    NORM_TABLE[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
      NORM_TABLE[i] = SmallFloat.byte4ToInt((byte) i);
    }
  }

Comment: That will definitely change the values from previous versions yes - the encoding should be more exact as this is an integer and not a float being encoded, so I'm guessing 53272 is actually closer to the length of the field?

Comment: yes i debugged further with smaller content, you are correct it is more closer in Sol 7 being int and not float, so now I assume that the scores and the ranks generated by Solr 7.1 are more accurate than the solr 6.6. Thanks a lot MatsLindh, this was really helpful.